# Facebook's OAuth "Given URL is not permitted by the Application configuration"

Tags: c#, facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0, facebook-c#-sdk

I was working on this program that connects my users through their **Facebook accounts**. It's been working quiet stable for the past couple of weeks, and I was able to add more value to my program during that period. However, starting today I was **unable to connect** through **Facebook** as I usually do. Whenever I ask for **App authorization** *(1st step)* I get a "*Given URL is not permitted by the Application configuration*" error, Even tho i didn't change anything in my **App Settings**.

I looked everywhere to check if maybe Facebook did some **Updates** or something, but couldn't find anything. Last time i logged in successfully was the **30th of March**.

How could have this happened if I didn't edit any of my code, and apparently **Facebook** didn't either! Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
    private string GenerateLoginUrlFacebook()
    {

        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();

        parameters.client_id = Globals.FBapplicationID;
        parameters.redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
        parameters.response_type = "token";
        parameters.display = "popup";

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Globals.FBextendedPermissionsNeeded))
            parameters.scope = Globals.FBextendedPermissionsNeeded;

        var fb = new FacebookClient();

        Uri loginUri = fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters);

        return loginUri.AbsoluteUri;

    }
```

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=542958419109491

Comment: This is currently not working, bug report already exists: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1580826392228832

Comment: nice find @CBroe... Apparently this is tied with **Facebook**, It started happening on the **3rd of April** with a last known working date of **30th of March**... I believe **Facebook** resolved the issue because i no longer get the error, fix was probably applied on the **4th of April**. Will keep everyone posted if the error starts reappearing